# getActionBar returning null in android L.

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

getActionBar returning null in android L. Although I have tried getting this.getRequestFeature, the moment actionbar reference is encountered nullpointerexception occurs. 
I want to implement actionbar with tabs in android L and actionbar.tablistener is deprecated.
Can someone please suggest a way to do it in android L?

Comment: Could you post the code, you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using swipe views - [Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

Comment: Got the error. Wrong action bar was imported. Cheers